# Caching text/image assets in performance-constrained environments

Tags: javascript, performance, browser-cache, opera, opera-presto

I'm working on an extremely performance-constrained devices. Because of the overhead of AJAX requests, I intend to aggressively cache text and image assets in the browser, but I need to configure the cache size per-device to as low as `1MB` of text and `9MB` of images -- quite a challenge for a multi-screen, graphical application.

Because the device easily hits the memory limit, I must be very cautious about how I manage my application's size: code file size, # of concurrent HTTP requests, # of JS processor cycles upon event dispatch, limiting CSS reflows, etc.  My question today is how to develop a size-restrained cache for text assets and images.

For text, I've rolled my own [cache](https://github.com/homeyjd/jkui/blob/master/src/cache.js) using `JSON.encode().length` for objects and `'string'.length` to approximate size.  The application manually gets/sets cache entries.  Upon hitting a configurable upper limit, the class garbage collects itself from `gcLimit` to `gcTarget` sizes, giving weight to the last-accessed properties (i.e., if something has been accessed recently, skip collecting that object the first time around).

For images, I intend to preload interface elements and let the browser deal with garbage collection itself by removing DOM elements and never persistently storing `Image()` objects.  For preloading, I will probably roll my own again -- I have examples to imitate like FiNGAHOLiC's ImgPreloader and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg723713.aspx).  I need to keep in mind features like "download window size" and "max cache requests" to ensure I don't inadvertently overload the device.

This is a huge challenge working in such a constrained environment, and common frameworks like Backbone don't support "max Collection size".  Elsewhere on SO, users quote limits of `5MB` for HTML5 `localStorag`e, but my goal is not session persistence, so I don't see the benefit.

I can't help feeling there might be better solutions.  Ideas?

*Edit*: @Xotic750: Thanks for the nod to IndexedDB. Sadly, this app is a standard web page built on Opera/Presto.  Even better, the platform offers no persistence.  Rock and a hard place :-/.

Comment: Thanks, @Ascherer, for the formatting fixes. Still getting used to SO's submission format.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage and sessionStorage ([DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Storage)) limits do not apply ([or can be overridden](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage#unlimited)) if the application is a browser extension (you don't mention what your application is).

localStorage is persistent

sessionStorage is sessional

Idea

Take a look at [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB) it is far more flexible though not as widely supported yet.

Also, some references to Chrome storage

[Managing HTML5 Offline Storage](https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/storage)

[chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)

Comment: The application is a web page loaded over network (no persistent client-side cache). Sadly, no browser-extension caveats.

Answer (score 0):

With modern javascript engines cpu/gpu performance is not an issue for most apps (except games, heavy animation or flash) on even low powered devices so I suspect your primary issues are memory and io. Optimising for one typically harms the other but I suspect that the issues below will be your primary concern.

I'm not sure you have any control over the cache usage of the browser. You can limit the memory taken up by the javascript app using methods like those you've suggested but the browser will still do it's own thing and that is probably the primary issue in terms of memory. By creating your own caches you will probably be actually duplicating data that is already cached by the browser and so exacerbate the memory problem. The browser (unless you're using something obscure) will normally do a better job of caching than is possible in javascript. In any case, I would strongly recommend letting the browser take care of garbage collection as there is no way in javascript to actually force browsers to free up the memory (they do garbage collection when they want, not when you tell them to). Do you have control over which browser is used on the device? If you do, then changing that may be the best way to reduce memory usage (also can you limit the size of the browser cache?).

For ajax requests ensure you fully understand the difference between GET and POST as this has big implications for caching on the browser and on proxies routing messages around the web (and therefore also affects the logic of your app). See if you can minimise the number of requests by grouping them together (JSON helps here). It is normally latency rather than bandwidth that is the issue for AJAX requests (but don't go too far as most browsers can do several requests concurrently). Ensure you construct your ajax manager to allow prioritisation of requests (i.e stuff that affects what the user sees is prioritised over preloading which is prioritised over analytics - half the web has a google analytics call the first thing that happens after page load, even before ads and other content is loaded).

Beyond that, I would suggest that images are likely to be the primary contributor to memory issues (I doubt code size even registers but you should ensure code is minimised with e.g. google closure). Reduce image resolutions to the bare minimum and experiment with file formats (e.g. gif or png might be significantly smaller than jpeg for some images (cartoons, logos, icons) but much larger for others (photos, gradients).

10MB of cache in your app may sound small but it is actually enormous compared with most apps out there. The majority leave caching to the browser (which in any case will probably still cache the data whether you want it to or not).

You mention Image objects which suggests you are using the canvas. There is a noticeable speed improvement if you create a new canvas to store the image (after which you can discard the Image object). You can use this canvas as the source of any image data you later need to copy to a canvas and as no translation between data types is required this is much faster. Given canvas operations often happen many times a frame this can be a significant boost.

Final note - don't use frameworks / libraries that were developed with a desktop environment in mind. To optimise performance (whether speed or memory) you need to understand every line of code. Look at the source code of libraries (many have some very clever optimised code) but assume that, in general, you are a special case for which they are not optimised.

Comment: You make a good point: disregarding the fact that the platform does not offer persistence, if the data is written to some form of swap or somewhat-static memory space, then perhaps it might not count against the memory limit for the application.  It's a long shot, but worth a test....